# Numero de semanas con Mes de acuerdo a fecha

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola buen dia tengo una consulta en sql server que me saca cuantas veces se ejecuto un reporte por sucursal y rango de fechas esto me lo coloca por dia cuantas veces y en que mes, pero quiero saber como
obterner cuantas veces corren el reporte por mensualmente, semanalmente, quincenal, anual yo ya lo tengo por dia pero no se como hacerlo como lo mennciono tengo la siguiente query

```
SELECT CVE_CONTROL AS CVE_PAG, CVE_SUC AS CVE_SUC,
        ISNULL(MESES.[2020-7-3],0) AS JUL3, ISNULL(MESES.[2020-7-4],0) AS JUL4
FROM(
    SELECT C1 AS CVE_SUC, C2 AS CVE_CONTROL, COUNT (C3) AS NUM_VECES, CONCAT(YEAR(C3),'-',MONTH(C3),'-',DAY(C3)) AS MES_HISTORIAL
    FROM KDHISCTRLVER  
    WHERE C3 BETWEEN '20200701' AND '20200730' 
    GROUP BY C1, C2, C3
) AS HISTORIAL
PIVOT(
SUM(NUM_VECES)
FOR[MES_HISTORIAL] IN ( [2020-7-3],[2020-7-4] )
) AS MESES
```

la query me trae por dia lo siguiente

```
JUL3    JUL4
 1       0
 1       0
```

pero me hace falta si quiero saber cuantas veces fue semanalmente, mensualmente, alguien que me de un tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen conceptos sobre lo que significa semanal, quincenal, mensual.... y cuando empieza o termina cada uno, que no expresas en la pregunta.

Por ejemplo semanal (¿de lunes a domingo?) o son 7 días anteriores a la ejecución de la query. No obstante son datos que puedes ir ajustando sin dificultad.

Una posible solución, es utilizar conjuntos correlativos, y de ellos extraer la función count, filtrando por el periodo que se necesita. Luego a la salida, realizar la unión partiendo de la base de que el de mayor rango (Anual), va a disponer de todos los anteriores por tanto se utiliza como enlace y a los siguientes conjuntos les haces un left join.

```
with anual
     as (SELECT C1 AS CVE_SUC
              , C2 AS CVE_CONTROL
              , count(*) as anual
                FROM KDHISCTRLVER
                WHERE C3 >= DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) -- PRIMER DÍA DEL AÑO
                group by c1
                       , c2),
     mensual
     as (SELECT C1 AS CVE_SUC
              , C2 AS CVE_CONTROL
              , count(*) as mensual
                FROM KDHISCTRLVER
                WHERE C3 >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)  -- PRIMER DÍA DEL MES
                group by c1
                       , c2),
     quincenal
     as (SELECT C1 AS CVE_SUC
              , C2 AS CVE_CONTROL
              , count(*) as quincena
                FROM KDHISCTRLVER
                WHERE C3 >= DATEADD(day, -15, GetDate()) and c3 <= GetDate()  -- Quincenal
                group by c1
                       , c2),
     Semanal
     As (SELECT C1 AS CVE_SUC
              , C2 AS CVE_CONTROL
              , count(*) as semana
                FROM KDHISCTRLVER
                WHERE C3 >= DATEADD(day, -7, GetDate()) and c3 <= GetDate()  -- Semanal
                group by c1
                       , c2)
     Select a.*
          , m.mensual
          , q.quincena
          , s.semana
            from anual AS a
                      left join mensual AS m on a.CVE_SUC = m.CVE_SUC and a.CVE_CONTROL = m.CVE_CONTROL
                      left join quincenal AS q on a.CVE_SUC = q.CVE_SUC and a.CVE_CONTROL = q.CVE_CONTROL
                      left join Semanal AS s on a.CVE_SUC = s.CVE_SUC and a.CVE_CONTROL = s.CVE_CONTROL;
```

[image: Salida]

[Funciones de fecha útiles](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/12/15/funciones-de-fecha-para-datetime-utiles/)

[Tablas de expresión común correlativas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-2-correlativos/)

Comment: gracias javi si me siver muchas gracias

Comment: como hacerle si lo quiero por rango de fechas DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0) ?

Comment: Por ejemplo... Where c3 >= DateAdd.....blablabla....,0) and c3 <= la otra opción.